# mv in script eports "cannot stat"

Tags: linux, bash, script, mv

I'm trying to write a script that adds the last accessed time to the end of the basename. Here is the script:

```
for f in *.doc; do
    DIR=$(pwd)
    FILENAME="$f"
    FILETYPE=${FILENAME##*.}
    BASENAME=${FILENAME%.*}
    LASTACCESS=$(stat --printf '%x' "$f" | sed 's/.........................$//' | sed 's/-//g')
    #echo "FILENAME : ""$FILENAME"
    #echo "FILETYPE : ""$FILETYPE"
    #echo "BASENAME : ""$BASENAME"
    echo "LASTACCESS : ""$LASTACCESS"
    echo "$DIR"
    echo mv "'""$DIR""/""$BASENAME"."$FILETYPE""'" "'""$BASENAME"-"$LASTACCESS"."$FILETYPE""'" > output
    mv -- "'""$DIR""/""$BASENAME"."$FILETYPE""'" "'""$BASENAME"-"$LASTACCESS"."$FILETYPE""'"
done
```

When I copy and past from the output file, it works but mv reports "cannot stat" on the source file when it runs in the script.

I've tried adding pwd to the code to include the full path name with the same results. There are spaces in the file names and the path.

Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I copy and past from the output file, it works but mv reports "cannot stat" on the source file when it runs in the script.

What you have in the output file is not the same as what you're running from the script, and you're adding *far too many* quotes in the script.

The shell removes one layer of quoting before running a command – it is the outermost layer of quoting that deals with spaces and such.

So when you use a twice-quoted `"'$dir'"` with, for example, 'echo', it receives `'the_dir'` and outputs a once-quoted command, so what you're pasting from the output.txt file is now only single-quoted. (And when you paste that back into Bash, the shell again removes one layer and the 'mv' command receives filenames with no quotes in them, which is the desired result.)

But when you give `"'$dir'"` to 'mv', it also receives `'the_dir'` as input... meaning that the `'` becomes *part of the file name.* And of course mv will not be able to find the file, because your actual files don't really have the single quote in their names.

In other words, what you need to use with 'echo' to *produce* a command is not the same as what you need for the command itself. So remove the mess from your `mv` invocation and just do a simple `"$dir/$basename"` with one level of quoting.

(It's fine if you do `"$dir"/"$basename"` as well; it also results in the same string after shell expansion.)

Comment: Thank you! You're suggestion worked like a charm. Part of the learning process.